# Getting ID of newly created object in save()

Tags: django, model, save

I want to save an object, so that the M2M get saved. Then I want to read out the M2M fields to do some calculations and set a field on the saved object.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(SomeOtherModel, through='SomeTable')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        m2m_items = SomeTable.objects.filter(item = self)
        # DO SOME STUFF WITH THE M2M ITEMS
```

The m2m_items won't turn up,. Is there any way to get these up  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some confusion here.

Once you've called `super`, `self.id` will have a value.

However, I don't understand the point of your `filter` call. For a start, you probably mean `get` rather than `filter` anyway, as filter gets a queryset, rather than a single instance. But even so, the call is pointless: you've *just* saved it, so whatever you get back from the database will be exactly the same. What's the point?

**Edit after question update** OK, thanks for the clarification. However, the model's `save()` method is not responsible for doing anything with M2M items. They need to be saved separately, which is the job of the form or the view.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I put the info wrong. I rewrote my question. What I do is I try to get the many2many items. But for some reason they won't turn up

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Im trying to use the m2m_changed signal now. models.signals.m2m_changed.connect(set_total_price, sender=Deal.product.through)   It won't call my set_total_price method for some reason. It works with the post_save signal... Ah well, I got some things to try again. Thanks alot.

Comment: For further reading: I ended up reading the M2M in the save_formset by iterating over the instances. Then I called up the saved Item and saved that with the new value.